# How to expose some specific fields of model_b based on a field of model_a?

Tags: python, django

I want to create a `ModelForm` which gonna show some specific field of `ControlInstruction` if `device_type` of Device is equals `DC`. Otherwise show all fields.

Suppose,

```
if device type == 'DC':
   show these filed in form-> on_off_flag, speed_flag, direction_flag
else:
   show all
```

How can I do that?

```py
class Device(models.Model):
    DEVICE_TYPES = (
            ('AC', 'AC MOTOR'),
            ('DC', 'DC MOTOR'),
    )
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    device_id = models.CharField(max_length=64, unique=True, blank=False)
    device_name = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=False)
    device_model = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    device_type = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DEVICE_TYPES, blank=False)
    location = models.CharField(max_length=150)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.device_name

class ControlInstruction(models.Model):
    DIRECTION_CHOICES = (
        ('FW', 'Forward'),
        ('BW', 'Backward'),
    )
    # OneToOneField is is similar to a ForeignKey with unique=True, but the “reverse”
    # side of the relation will directly return a single object.
    device = models.OneToOneField(Device, on_delete=models.CASCADE, primary_key=True)
    on_off_flag = models.BooleanField(default=False)
    voltage_flag = models.FloatField(max_length=20, default=0)
    current_flag = models.FloatField(max_length=20, default=0)
    speed_flag = models.IntegerField(default=0, validators=[MinValueValidator(0), MaxValueValidator(100)])
    direction_flag = models.CharField(max_length=2, choices=DIRECTION_CHOICES, default='FW')
    frequency_flag = models.IntegerField(default=0)
```

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend creating two forms, one including only the fields for a DC device, and one form with all of the fields. Then in your view, choose which form to use based on the device_type.

Answer (score 0):

```
class DeviceForm(forms.ModelForm):
     class Meta:
         model = Device
         fields = "__all__"

     def __init__(self,*args,**kwargs):
         super().__init__(*args, **kwargs)
         if self.instance.pk:
              if self.instance.device_type != "DC":
                   del self.fields["on_off_flag"]
                   del self.fields["speed_flag"]
                   del self.fields["direction_flag"]
```

But I dont recommended since you will find that this approach is very limited